# C# WinForms - Refresh a TreeView with System Directories (TreeViewMS)

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, refresh, nullreferenceexception

I have a TreeView with Multiple Selection (TreeView MS) component showing all the system directories in a Form; I tried to Develop an event in the Form that when 'F5' it's pressed, the TreeView Refresh itself (to find new directories or remove deleted ones).

The problem lies when the TreeView doesn't refresh itself, it shows the NullReferenceException in the TreeView in Program class, here my method to Refresh:

```
private void frmInit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.F5)
        ReloadTreeView();
}

private void ReloadTreeView(){
    if(TreeViewFiles.Nodes != null){
        TreeViewFiles.Nodes.Clear(); //maybe this way isn't the best to do this.
        exArq.CreateDirectoryTree(TreeViewFiles);
    }
}
```

here is the complete Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TreeView MS.dll Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The Method CreateDirectoryTree makes a search of system directories and create the Tree with them:

```
public void CreateDirectoryTree(TreeView treeView) {

    foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives()) {

        TreeNode rootDirectoryNode = new TreeNode();
        rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
        rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
        rootDirectoryNode.Text = drv.Name;

        switch (drv.DriveType) {

            case DriveType.Network:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NetworkDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NetworkDiskIcon;
                break;

            case DriveType.CDRom:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.CDDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.CDDiskIcon;
                break;

            case DriveType.Fixed:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.LocalDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.LocalDiskIcon;
                break;

            case DriveType.Removable:
                rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.RemovalDiskIcon;
                rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.RemovalDiskIcon;
                break;

        }

        bool isSystemDirectory = drv.Name.ToString() == Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);

        if (isSystemDirectory) {
            rootDirectoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
            rootDirectoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.SystemDiskIcon;
        }

        rootDirectoryNode.Nodes.Add(String.Empty);

        treeView.Nodes.Add(rootDirectoryNode);
    }

}
```

I Also have another method to find the Directories when I Expand a node:

```
public TreeNode GetDirectoriesAndFilesNodes(TreeNode parentNode) {

    string nodePath = parentNode.FullPath + Constants.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(nodePath);
    parentNode.Nodes[0].Remove();
    try {

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in rootDirectory.GetDirectories()) {

            TreeNode directoryNode = new TreeNode();
            directoryNode.Text = dir.Name;
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(String.Empty);
            directoryNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DirectoryIcon;
            directoryNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DirectoryIcon;
            parentNode.Nodes.Add(directoryNode);

        }

        foreach (FileInfo file in rootDirectory.GetFiles()) {

            bool isExcel = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_EXCEL_X) || Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_EXCEL);

            bool isZipedFile = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_RAR) || Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_ZIP);

            bool isTextFile = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).ToLower().Equals(Constants.EXTENSION_TXT);

            TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode();
            fileNode.Text = file.Name;

            if (isExcel) {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ExcelFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ExcelFileIcon;
            } else if (isZipedFile) {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ZipedFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.ZipedFileIcon;
            } else if (isTextFile) {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.TextFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.TextFileIcon;
            } else {
                fileNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.GenericFileIcon;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.GenericFileIcon;
            }

            parentNode.Nodes.Add(fileNode);
        }

    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
        TreeNode errorNode = new TreeNode();
        errorNode.Text = "Negate Acess!";
        errorNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NoPermissionIcon;
        errorNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.NoPermissionIcon;
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(errorNode);
    } catch (IOException) {
        TreeNode errorNode = new TreeNode();
        errorNode.Text = "The Driver isn't readdy!";
        errorNode.ImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DriverNotReady;
        errorNode.SelectedImageIndex = ImageIndexs.DriverNotReady;
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(errorNode);
    }

    return parentNode;
}
```

I put a breakpoint into the code to see where exactly the exception is been throw and I Found out that: After I Reloaded the , The Exception it's throw in the Program class

```
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmInit()); // EXCEPTION !!
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a little unclear, but im guessing you just need some error trapping in your tree walk to populate down, if you cant access, stop there, move on to the next.

Comment: Please share the `exArq.CreateTree` function

Comment: Step through the `exArq.CreateTree` method in the debugger. It should be easy to identify the null variable.

Comment: Is `exArq` null? Put a breakpoint on that line... Also, use [`Path.HasExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.hasextension(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `file.Extension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".txt")`.

Comment: @DavidPine No `exArq` is a object that I create to handle with the TreeView. Cool. thanks for the tip, I didn't know the Path.HasExtension tool.

Comment: @BugFinder, good idea, I'm trying to see where I can put this error trapping, could you help me on that?